# MongoDB query with and in the same object array

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
"level1": [
{},
{},
{
  "level2": {
    "level3": [
      [
        {
          "second": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "second": 1,
          "label": "A",
          "frame": 40
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "second": 2,
          "label": "A",
          "frame": 60
        },
        {
          "second": 2,
          "label": "B",
          "frame": 60
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "second": 3,
          "label": "B",
          "frame": 90
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
]
}
```

I would like to find the elements A and B when they occur contemporarily in the same second. I'm able to find label "A" or label "B" but I would like that the result of the query is *second 2* or a list of all seconds when both elements appear.

Comment: Is this always the exact structure? or do we have an unbounded number of levels?

Comment: this is the exact structure.